# NoReverseMatch at ///

Tags: html, python, django

Es para una pagina tipo blog en la cual una pagina (posteo) se relaciona con un usuario y ese usuario necesita de una profilepage.
Necesito relacionar el Profile con el User pero lo que está haciendo es ir al id del profile en vez del id del user.

Este es el modelo Profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    nombre= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField()
    web_site=models.URLField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nombre)
```

la view

```
class PerfilDetalle(DetailView): 
    model=Profile
    template_name="profile_page.html"
```

la url

```
path('profile/<pk>', views.PerfilDetalle.as_view(), name="profile"),
```

el template html

```
{% for pagina in paginas %}

<h5>{{ pagina.titulo }}</h5>
<h1>{{ pagina.user }}</h1>

<a href="{% url 'profile' profile.user.id %}">{{ pagina.user }}</a> |
<a href="{% url 'paginadetalle' pagina.id %}">Leer mas</a>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if user.id == pagina.user.id %}
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'editarpagina' pagina.id %}">Editar</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'pagina_borrar' pagina.id %}">Borrar</a>
        
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

<br>
<br>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'nuevopost'  %}">Publicar</a>
    {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

[image: mensaje de error]

Y el error arroja el sitio